# I have an element show on mouseover now I would like to hide it once I mouse out. How do I do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" name="div1" >Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" name="div2" >Page1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" name="div3" >page2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" name="div4" >page3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div>

    <div class="div1" style="display:none">
        Test
    </div>

    <div class="div2" style="display:none">
        Test...
    </div>

    <div class="div3" style="display:none">
        Test 1
    </div>

    <div class="div4" style="display:none">
        Test 2
    </div>

</div>
```

Along with the following jQuery:

```
$('a').mouseover

(function() {
    var divname = this.name;
    $("." + divname).show("slow");
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puffnstuff/r739G/)

I want to be able to mouseout and hide once I leave the boxes that appear not on "a". How do I do this?

Comment: In future, can you include all code snippets in the question **as well** as linking to jsfiddle. SO questions should stand alone from other resources, so that the question is useful for future users even if the resource goes away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wow Im sorry I didnt understand the question initially I guess, see below. This binds `mouseout` to the `div` you just showed, so it will stay until you move out of it, not the `a`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/r739G/10/)**

```
$('a').mouseover(function() {
    var divname = this.name;
    $("." + divname).show("slow").mouseout(function(){$(this).hide('slow')});
});
```

I would recommend changing your markup however to have the div's as children of the li's, or at the very least, putting them closer to the a's once hovered over because if you notice you can hover over all of the a elements but never mouseout of the div causing them to stay. Then you could do something like the following:

```
$('li').hover(function() {
    var divname = this.name;
    $("." + divname).show("slow");
},function(){
    var divname = this.name;
    $("." + divname).hide("slow");
});
```

Comment: wow thanks so much! I was actually a lot close then I thought I tried  $("." + divname).show("slow").(this).mouseout(); which of course didn't work

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/genesis/r739G/1/

```
$('a').mouseover(function() {
    var divname = this.name;
    $("." + divname).show("slow");
});

$('a').mouseout(function(){
    var divname = this.name;
    $("." + divname).hide("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this....

```
(function() {
    var divname = this.name;
    $("." + divname).hide("slow");
});
```